# Make div stick to non-child div with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, owl-carousel-2

So I'm trying to make a double slider in Owl-Carousel 2.0,
The first slider has 9 images, which means it has 9 dots. These dots are in placed in a container, #customdots. I'm trying to make the position of these dots be: horizontally centered (which works), and appear on top of the second slider, so position, bottom should be the height of the second slider (#sync2).
I tried using JQuery to do this, with the following line of code:

```
$("#customDots").css('bottom', $("#sync2").outerHeight()+ "px");
```

However, this doesn't get the actual #sync2 height, and it doesn't update on moving the window, neither does using height().

How would I go about making this #customDots div stick to the top of #sync2, when it can't be a child of #sync2?

See full codepen here: http://codepen.io/JJvanSteijn/pen/aJxgdW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap `#sync2` in an element (I created `#sync2Container`), use that new element to position the second slider at the bottom of the window, and just add the dots to the top of that element. http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/JWgKxJ

Comment: @JeroenvanSteijn You've asked more questions in the comments than you did in your original question. Please avoid introducing a bunch of new questions that have nothing to do with the answer in the comments when someone answers the question in your post, and keep the relevant questions in the post. That said, each question should have a clear, single question. If you have new problems, you should try to figure it out on your own, and if you can't, ask a new question.

Comment: @JeroenvanSteijn and be sure to select an answer as the solution (checkmark by the answers) if the issue in your OP is resolved.

Comment: You're absolutely right, my bad. I selected your answer and might make a new post soon.

Comment: thanks for pointing out etiquette here, since this was my first question ever. It makes a lot more sense using StackOverflow the way you describe it, especially for people googling on these questions, as well as trying things out for yourself before just relying on other people. I fixed almost all of the questions I asked you, except for one which might be more advanced. Would you mind to take a look at it?

Comment: @JeroenvanSteijn you're welcome. Yeah the goal is to ask specific, clear questions that will help people who google/search for the same thing. And we all do this for karma, and we may not know how to do all of the things you asked in the comments. It's also important to mark your question as solved as soon as it's resolved so that people don't continue to provide answers when your question is already resolved.

Comment: @JeroenvanSteijn your other question is pretty tricky, and likely isn't the kind of thing that will help someone else. It's more of someone giving you free tutor work on the project than a clear question someone could google for 2 years from now and solve their own problem. I would recommend re-writing that to be more general and not so specific to your project. It would probably take someone a while to answer that, and it isn't going to help anyone else... when there are hundreds of questions an hour on here that are easier and will help others, so that's where people will spend their time.

Comment: wow, now that you lay out the reasoning behind the kind of questions placed on SO I feel stupid for not realizing myself. Rephrasing my question would come down to: make div move another div up when it reaches it's height, but that might not be general enough. Do you think you can point me in the right direction as to what to google for so I might not even have to ask myself? Seriously thanks tho, if there's anything I can do in return let me know.

Comment: @JeroenvanSteijn you deleted the post and I don't remember exactly what you were trying to do. But I think you need to come up with a different approach entirely. I remember it was a really roundabout approach, which is part of the problem asking about how to do it on SO. No one is going to re-factor it entirely for you, and getting what you had to work would be a total hack. If I recall correctly, you were trying to detect if one element had moved under another, and if it had, you wanted to move part of the stuff in one of those elements to another spot so that it was visible.

Comment: @JeroenvanSteijn if you don't know where to start, maybe post it to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add height to the CSS for `#sync2`:

```
#sync2{height:210px}
```

and use JS code to get the height:

```
$('#customDots').css('padding-bottom','0px');
$('#customDots').css('bottom',sync2.outerHeight());
```

Hope it's useful.